# A q,t-extension of Plancherel Measure thru Yang-Mills Theory ?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, rt.representation-theory, q-analogs, pr.probability

Buried in the physics paper by [Nekrasov and Okounkov](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306238), a strange identity is proven:
$$ \prod_{n > 0} (1 - q^n)^{\mu^2-1} = \sum_{\mathbf{k}} q^{|\mathbf{k}|} \prod_{\square \in k} \left( 1 - \frac{\mu^2}{h(\square)^2}\right) $$
where the left side is a q-series and the right side is the sum over all partitions.  Ihis was proven by physical considerations, evaluating the Yang-Mills partition function in 2 different ways.

The partitions could index representations of the permutation group $S_n$.    We can define measure on partitions, $\mathrm{Irr}(S_n)$ by

$$ \mathbb{P}\_{\mu, t} (\mathbf k) = \prod_{n \geq 1} (1-t^n)^{1-\mu^2} q^{|\mathbf{k}|} \prod_{\square \in k} \left( 1 - \frac{\mu^2}{h(\square)^2}\right) $$

In fact, 3 years later Alexei Borodin explains this formula [interpolates between  uniform and Plancherel measures](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601019) on partitions.

---

Can this be extended to a q,t-deformation of uniform measure on the permutation group?  Maybe through something similar to Robinson-Schensted correspondence.

Comment: I fixed the typos in your formulas.

Comment: This identity was also found independently in:

MR2218820 (2007c:17009) 
Westbury, Bruce W.
Universal characters from the Macdonald identities.
Adv. Math.  202  (2006),  no. 1, 50--63.


Comment: Have you looked at Theorem 1 in

MR2837629 (2012i:05019)  Dehaye, Paul-Olivier ;  Han, Guo-Niu .
A multiset hook length formula and some applications.
Discrete Math.  311  (2011),  no. 23-24, 2690--2702.

?


Answer (score 4):

Recently there is [An insertion algorithm associated with q-Whittaker functions](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6716)

defining a q-weighted form of the Robinson-Schensted algorithm.

The [MacDonald processes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4408) contain many examples of "integrable" combinatorial processes on [Gelfand-Tsetlin patterns](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211289) (see this [talk](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/ivcorwin/talk_macdonald_neutral.pdf)).

- q-Whittaker processes
- [Hall-Littlewood processes](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2138)
- Random matrices
- [Whittaker processes](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgas/bielefeld11.pdf)
- [Kingman partition structures](http://icerm.brown.edu/materials/Slides/sp-f12-w1/Clusters_and_features_from_combinatorial_stochastic_processes_%255D_Tamara_Broderick,_University_of_California,_Berkeley.pdf)
- [schur processes](http://arxiv.org/abs/math.RT/9907127)

Many of these feel nature from the point of view of representation theory of symmetric groups.  Macdonald functions are a q,t-deformation of this.