# extensions of the Nekrasov-Okounkov formula

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, rt.representation-theory

This post is related to the issues addressed in

[A q,t-extension of Plancherel Measure thru Yang-Mills Theory ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109053/a-q-t-extension-of-plancherel-measure-thru-yang-mills-theory?rq=1)

however the generalization/interpolation which John Mangual asks for looks  different from the one proposed here.

In what follows $\lambda$ will be an integer partition (of size $|\lambda| = n$),
the notation $b \in \lambda$ will indicate that $b$ is a cell or *box* in the Young diagram of $\lambda$, and $\mathrm{h}(b)$ will denote the
*hook length* of the hook determined by $b$ in $\lambda$'s Young diagram.
Furthermore $\dim(\lambda)$ will denote the number of saturated chains
$\lambda^{(0)} \subset \cdots \subset \lambda^{(n)}$ in the Young lattice $\Bbb{Y}$ beginning at the empty partition $\lambda^{(0)} = \emptyset$ and
ending at $\lambda^{(n)} = \lambda$. Equivalently $\dim(\lambda)$ is the dimension of the corresponding irreducible representation $V_\lambda$ of the symmetric group $S_n$.

The Nekrasov-Okounkov formula is the following $t$-deformation of the classical identity for the partition function, namely:

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle 
\sum_{\lambda \in \Bbb{Y}} z^{|\lambda|} \,\prod_{b \in \lambda}  \,
\Big(1 - {t \over {\mathrm{h}^2(b})} \Big) 
&\displaystyle = \
\sum_{n \geq 0} \, {z^n \over {n !}} \, \sum_{|\lambda| = n} \, 
{\dim^2(\lambda) \over {n!}} \, \prod_{b \in \lambda} \, \big(
\mathrm{h}^2(b) - t \big) \\ \\
&\displaystyle \stackrel{!}{=} \
\prod_{k \geq 1} \, \big(1 - z^k \big)^{t-1}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

with the specialization $t=0$ corresponding to the well known identity for the generating function of $p(n)$, the number of integer partitions of $n \geq 0$:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n \geq 0} \, p(n) \, z^n = \prod_{k \geq 1} \, \big( 1 - z^k \big)^{-1}
\end{equation}

My first question concerns the internal sum

\begin{equation}
\sum_{|\lambda| = n} \, 
{\dim^2(\lambda) \over {n!}} \, \prod_{b \in \lambda} \, \big(
\mathrm{h}^2(b) - t \big) 
\end{equation}

which we can view as an expectation value for the $t$-statistic $H_t(\lambda) = \prod_{b \in \lambda} \, \big(\mathrm{h}^2(b) - t \big) $ with respect to the
*Plancherel* measure $\mu^{(n)}_\mathrm{P}(\lambda) = {1 \over {n!}} \dim^2(\lambda)$ on the set of partitions of size $|\lambda| =n$. Let's denote this expectation value as $\langle H_t \rangle_{\mathrm{P},n}$. Clearly it is a polynomial in $t$.

> **Question 1.** Is there a nice (e.g. combinatorial) formula  describing how $\langle H_t \rangle_{\mathrm{P},n}$ factorizes as a
> polynomial in $t$? Indeed, should it factorize nicely?

Instead of using the (family of) Plancherel measure(s) $\mu^{(n)}_\mathrm{P}$
we may use a coherent, ergodic family of measures $\mu^{(n)}_\varphi$
associated to another choice of normalised, minimal, harmonic function $\varphi: \Bbb{Y} \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}_{>0}$. Recall that the
measure $\mu_\varphi^{(n)}$
on the set of partitions $\lambda$ of size $|\lambda| = n$ is defined
by

\begin{equation}
\mu_\varphi^{(n)} (\lambda) := \ \dim(\lambda) \, \varphi(\lambda) 
\end{equation}

Among the supply of minimal, normalised, harmonic functions
are the *Schur*-states $\varphi_{\bf x}$ defined by $\varphi_{\bf x}(\lambda) = {\scriptstyle \frak{S}}_\lambda(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$ where
${\scriptstyle \frak{S}}_\lambda$ is the Schur function associated to
$\lambda \in \Bbb{Y}$ and
where ${\bf x} = (x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$ is any sequence of positive real numbers with $0 \leq x_k \leq 1$
and $x_{k+1} \leq x_k$ for all $k \geq 1$ and with convergent sum
$\sum_{k \geq 1} x_k = 1$. Accordingly define the corresponding *Schur* measure(s) by
$\mu^{(n)}_{\bf x}(\lambda) = \dim(\lambda) \, {\scriptstyle \frak{S}}_\lambda(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$.

> **Question 2.** Is a version of the Nekrasov-Okounkov formula known where the role of the Plancherel measure $\mu^{(n)}_\mathrm{P}$ is
> replaced by a Schur measure $\mu^{(n)}_{\bf x}$? Specifically an
> identity for
> \begin{equation} \sum_{n \geq 0} \, {z^n \over {n !}} \,
>  \sum_{|\lambda| = n} \,  \mu^{(n)}_\mathrm{x} \, \prod_{b \in \lambda}
>  \, \big( \mathrm{h}^2(b) - t \big) \ = \ ? \end{equation}

It's not clear to me what the $t=0$ version would be; related perhaps to some kind of *content* identity.

*Post-Script.* In light of the interpolation question asked in

[A q,t-extension of Plancherel Measure thru Yang-Mills Theory ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109053/a-q-t-extension-of-plancherel-measure-thru-yang-mills-theory?rq=1)

I would add that there is a (family of) coherent, ergodic measures
$\mu_{{\bf x}, \tau}^{(n)}$ interpolating between the Plancherel measure(s) $\mu^{(n)}_\mathrm{P}$ and the Schur measures
$\mu^{(n)}_{\bf x}$ for any choice of (admissible) real sequence
${\bf x}=(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots)$. The normalised, non-negative,
minimal, harmonic function $\varphi_{{\bf x},\tau}$ associated to
the family $\mu_{{\bf x}, \tau}^{(n)}$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\varphi_{{\bf x},\tau}(\lambda) \ = \
\sum_{k = 0}^n \, {\tau^k (1-\tau)^{n-k} \over {(n-k)!}} \,
\sum_{|\eta| = k} \, \varphi_{\bf x}(\eta) \dim(\eta, \lambda)
\end{equation}

where $\dim(\eta, \lambda)$ is the number of saturated chains in $\Bbb{Y}$
joining $\eta$ and $\lambda$ with $|\eta| \leq |\lambda|$. Clearly $\varphi_{{\bf x},1} = \varphi_{\bf x}$ and $\varphi_{{\bf x},0} =
\varphi_\mathrm{P}$ where $\varphi_\mathrm{P}(\lambda) = {1 \over {n!}} 
\dim(\lambda)$ is the *Plancherel state*.
The existence of this interpolation (which is an special property enjoyed by $1$-differential posets and discovered by Goodman and Kerov) adds weight to the intuition that there should be some kind of $\tau$-deformation of the Nekrasov-Okounkov formula in the *direction* of ${\bf x}$.

thanks, ines.

Comment: For your first question the data is not promising. For $5\leq n\leq 20$ there is exactly one irreducible (over $\mathbb{Q}$) factor of degree $>1$. These degrees are: $(2,3,3,4,3,8,6,9,8,9,12,13,11,13,12,16)$. The degree of the polynomial is $n$.

Comment: Actually that's good news because I am doing the same computation for the Young-Fibonacci lattice and starting for $n=5$ I get some terrible irreducible factor.